# how to get the value of all p and h tags in a html page excluding all other tags

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am trying to load a HTML page into my app. I want to show only the content of the HTML page.
please help me with a javascript function where I can loop through all the **p** tags and get the content of the `<p>` tags to display in a **TextView** as string.

```
<html><body>" +
        "<h1>First</h1><p>text text text</p>" +
        "<h1>Second</h1>more text" +
         <p>text text text</p>
           <p>text text text</p>
          <p>text text text</p>
        "</body></html>
```

Comment: Just remember that if you're trying to make your solution generic you're going to run into issues: not everyone bounds all of their text in 'p' tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not want to use jQuery just do:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++)
{
    alert(paragraphs[i].innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: thanks but it gives me all the inner tags like id and stuff like that how would get rid of inner tags within

Comment: In IE there is also an .innerText, but this does not work in FireFox. jQuery solves this by providing the .text() function. You would have to do some cross browser scripting. But there a lot of samples in the web.

Answer (score 2):

For looking by separated selectors you can write them by comma in jQuery

```
$("p, :header").each(function(index, element){ 
   console.info($(element).html());  
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Here one line jquery script will do. `$("body p").text()`

If you want to get per `<p>` line, you can also do it like this

```
$("body").children("p").each(function(e,v){
    alert($(v).text());
});​
```