# javascript regex to split <p>x</p>

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to split an HTML string by every p tag so I get the following array:

```
array{
 '<p>my text</p>',
 '<p>my text2</p>',
 ...
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
array = articleContent.split(/<p>|(?=<\/p>)/g);
```

But the outcome is:

```
array{
 '</p><p>my text',
 '</p><p>my text2',
 ...
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to split? please put a sample of your expected outcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for replacing <p class="someClass"> with <h2> tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284999/regex-for-replacing-p-class-someclass-with-h2-tag) It's the same without replace and other classes.

Comment: what is the html source you are dealing with ?

Comment: by the way, since you are in the client side, why not use javascript alone (or a library) to parse the html ? Sounds better. With jQuery, for instance, all you would need to do is $("yourHtmlElement p") and loop over the results, extracting text().

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get the value of all p and h tags in a html page excluding all other tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625048/how-to-get-the-value-of-all-p-and-h-tags-in-a-html-page-excluding-all-other-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this!

```js
const re = /\<p>.*?<\/p>/g; //check anything that start/end with tag
const article = "<p>lorem</p> asteroids <p>Ipsum</p>";
const matches = article.match(re); //get the matches
var r = Array.from(matches); //create an array from matches!
console.log(r); // CHECK OUT!
```

Comment: if you need to test against multiple line `const re = /\<p>.*?<\/p>/gm;`

Answer (score -1):

Try using the following regex. It'd be great if you could update your question with example data.

`/(<p>[A-Za-z\s0-9]+<\/p>)/g`

Check the output [here](https://regex101.com/r/dH6cO4/1).

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
/<p>(.*)<\/p>/g.exec('<p>my text</p>')[1];
```

Returns:

```
"my text"
```

Comment: Can you explain this a bit? Popped up in review queue.

Comment: @Will full solution: 
data = [ '<p>my text</p>', '<p>my text2</p>']; resultArray = []; data.forEach(function(element) { resultArray.push( /<p>(.*)<\/p>/g.exec(element)[1] ); });

Answer (score -1):

You could go with

```
/<p\b.*?<\/p\b[^>]*>/g
```

It'll match the initial tag and everything up to the closing one (including attributes). And of course... If you've got nested tags, you're screwed.

Get every match like this:

```js
var str='<p style="border:1px solid #000">First paragraph with a border</p> is my <p style="color:red">Next paragraph in red</span></p>',
 re = /<p\b.*?<\/p\b[^>]*>/g,
    m,
    resultingArray = [];

while (m = re.exec(str) )
{
    resultingArray.push(m[0]);
}

document.write(resultingArray.join('--------------------') + '<br/>');
```